# Previous Object becomes NULL after TlsSetValue

Tags: c++, thread-local-storage

In my C++ dll I am using Thread local storage to store and retrieve thread specific information.

The thread specific info gets packed in a object `pInfo`. I am allocating once in DLL attach and then using storing the pInfo for each thread using TlsSetValue.

```
PInfo *pInfo = TlsGetValue(tlsIndex);
if(pInfo == NULL)
{
   pInfo = new PInfo();
   errCheck = TlsSetValue(tlsIndex, pInfo);
}
```

After some function callbacks and filling the pInfo. In a particular point i push this pInfo (a pointer) to a static vector (which is defined as below).

```
vector<PInfo*>* swapBucket;
```

Using `swapBucket->push_back(pInfo);` i push this object . After pushing this , i need to refresh the existing TLS index storage. So i am assigning NULL to existing TLS index.

`errCheck = TlsSetValue(tlsIndex, NULL);`

After setting this, i verify whether the lastly inserted pInfo in the `swapBucket` is valid. But surprisingly it is NULL.

```
       if(swapBucket->size() > 0)
        {
            if(swapBucket->back() == NULL)
            {
                fileLogObj->WriteLog("[WARNING]","Last Element is NULL",2);
            }
        }
```

This does not happens all the time. Only some times it happens. (May be once in 5000 times -  Sometime it never happens). Most of the time whatever object i push into the vector remains same(even after refreshing with TlsSetValue). Why the pushed object to vector becomes NULL.? (I am not deleting the object too - After some processing with those vector objects i delete those pInfos)

Comment: If `swapBucket` is not thread-local and access to it is not synchronized then it may get corrupted eventually.

Comment: why there is a downvote? can that person explain?

Comment: I'm not him, however the reasons for downvote are quite obvious: no [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) provided and wrong tags (this question is about WinAPI and has nothing to do with C++11).

Comment: read about [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Although it is impossible to say from your question what exactly is wrong, when you describe a problem using the words *threading* and *sometimes*, most probably you're missing some synchronization somewhere.

For example, `std::vector` is not thread safe. You need to ensure sequential access to it, for example using a mutex:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex swapBucketMtx;
std::vector<PInfo*>* swapBucket;

{
    // First lock the mutex
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> swapBucketLock(swapBucketMtx);

    // Now you may access swapBucket
    swapBucket->push_back(pInfo);
    if(swapBucket->size() > 0)
    {
        if(swapBucket->back() == NULL)
        {
            fileLogObj->WriteLog("[WARNING]","Last Element is NULL",2);
        }
    }

    // mutex will unlock automatically on scope exit
}
```